# Compiling list of links off of pastebin Python

Tags: python, html, regex, lxml, partitioning

Currently trying to extract links of of pastebin using python. What I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
from random import randint
import time
from lxml import etree
from time import sleep
import random

a = requests.get('http://pastebin.com/JGM3p9c9')
scrape = BeautifulSoup(a.text, 'lxml')
linkz = scrape.find_all("textarea", {"id":"paste_code"})

rawlinks = str(linkz)
partition1 = rawlinks.partition('\\r')[0]
links = partition1.partition('">')[-1]
```

I cant seem to get python to compile all of the `http://` formatted links but only the first... Using regex's I found online didnt work

End goal I'm trying to get the links into a list, in which I can send requests to all of the links in the list I compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you do not have to extract the complete tag and change it into `str`. Better way to achieve it is:

```
#                      `next` to extract content within tag v
#    instead use `find` v                                   v
>>> my_links = scrape.find("textarea", {"id":"paste_code"}).next
```

where `my_links` will hold the value:

```
u'http://www.walmart.com\r\nhttp://www.target.com\r\nhttp://www.lowes.com\r\nhttp://www.sears.com'
```

In order to convert this string to your desired `list` of links, you may split the string on `\r\n` as:

```
>>> my_links.split('\r\n')
[u'http://www.walmart.com', u'http://www.target.com', u'http://www.lowes.com', u'http://www.sears.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate through a couple of layers of HTML but I had a look at the pastebin page and I think this code will find what you want (sorry for switching a couple of modules I just use these ones instead)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

a = urllib.request.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/JGM3p9c9')
scrape = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')

x1 = scrape.find_all('div', id = 'selectable')
for x2 in x1:
    x3 = x2.find_all('li')
    for x4 in x3:
        x5 = x4.find_all('div')
        for x6 in x5:
            print(x6.string)
```

Next time you need to scrape a specific thing I advice looking at the HML of the website by right-clicking and selecting 'Inspect Element'. also you can do:

```
print(scrape.prettify())
```

To get a better idea of how the HTML is nested.

Answer (score 1):

Forget using BS to parse the HTML - in this specific case, you can get the content of the PasteBin directly, and turn this into a one liner.

```
import requests
links = [link.strip() for link in requests.get('http://pastebin.com/raw/JGM3p9c9').text.split('\n')]
```

You can also split on `\r\n`